# image repeat (not background image)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created a unique  dynamic watermark image to every user using the system. i wanted to make it repeatable not as a background, in background images you can't print it with the rest of the page he is one, I want to control him by printing his id as a watermark image repeated all over the data so he cant use it anywhere else, is there any other way to make it possible to repeat an image to be printed out?

I use like this code

```
<div class="container">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
     A lot of content here maybe more like not less than 20 row  ...
</div>
```

and the JS :

```
    $("<div><img src='http://www.adobe.com/business/calculator/VIP/image/loader.gif' width='30px' style='margin-left:45%; margin-top:4%;' repeat /></div>").css({
    position: "absolute",
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    opacity:0.4,
    background: "#ccc"
}).appendTo($(".container").css("position", "relative"));
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? I would say yes, using javascript/jquery with a position absolute / z-index > 1 image that is repeatedly appended to the body

Comment: Welcome to SO. This question is pretty unclear. You should include the code of what you've tried so far or deliver a more precice description. At first glance I'd say: Don't rely on html elements for watermarks or other security relevant factors. No matter what you do, the output can and will be manipulated by users. Include the watermarks in the images(?) before you send them to the browser.

Comment: question itself makes very little sense without more context and better explanation of goals

Comment: this is the code i wanted to repeat any image not the loader image

Comment: If you don't actually change the image itself (and add the watermark directly to it), everybody can get the "clean" image within seconds or even automated by scripts. A HTML-based overlay is a unsatisfying approach in my eyes.

Comment: i know its unsatisfying even to me, but i can protect the data else, and even know who is accessing it